# TypeScript keyof index type is too wide

Tags: typescript, keyof

Apologies, I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but I'm not sure what to google. Please do edit my question if the terms in the title are wrong.

I have something like this:

```js
type RowData = Record<string, unknown> & {id: string}; 


type Column<T extends RowData, K extends keyof T> = {  
  key: K; 
  action: (value: T[K], rowData: T) => void;
}

type RowsAndColumns<T extends RowData> = {
  rows: Array<T>; 
  columns: Array<Column<T, keyof T>>; 
}
```

And TypeScript should be able to infer the types of the `action` functions, by examining the shape of the rows, and what `key` value has been given to the column:

ie:

```js
function myFn<T extends RowData>(config: RowsAndColumns<T>) {

}

myFn({
  rows: [
    {id: "foo", 
      bar: "bar", 
      bing: "bing", 
      bong: {
        a: 99, 
        b: "aaa"
      }
    }
  ], 
  columns: [
    {
      key: "bar", 
      action: (value, rowData) => {
          console.log(value);
      }
    },
     {
      key: "bong", 
      action: (value, rowData) => {
          console.log(value.a); //Property 'a' does not exist on type 'string | { a: number; b: string; }'.

      }
    }
  ]
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQFwngDgpsBKD2B3AIgQxK4BeOUDG8ATgCYA8AziIQJYB2A5gDTACutA1rUrQHzABkwAN7ViALmCUaDAL4BuYAChl4aMADC8ADYsAtrVIAVYFAAeIKLWLk4SNBmYBpE+cvXg7KGHgAzYIb4cIUVgJVDPMAlHBRDgVDwQanhaCQAKADdUHSgJQwBtRwBdZkI7dFRcgEpsPnT4UTlFGRVIGAREcgBBK00dfXIjFwsrG3b7VEDhWNKOiU7CQlQwIx4Y0II+2nI5haXSXr0DQ2YI338eVaVm5R82BKTaYF0wADEjobdRsoweVIJaHzUegSdpdHraQ4DALVYJNZSKZ5vVLBUIzbbAPKxUIicTAABEPng8DxzCxoWAACNUIQJHiqYQSWFyaEKXRgfjWQxGWSWcl2SjmeSKsAAJwi0mC8kU2moWV4nnAZrMpXAYpMjaQiSY5kC5kRWn0vFxGz-SgSwXxRLJNKZbIlb6oapYPi6yXAU3aKAAOi08HoGSyLCglUakpVoRkjB5rvCXgNfO5kstDxtgag9pQ5SdLoVzI9Wm9vv9tqDXsdCgA9BWAAqlaCEcDAADkqCbwGI8CgNi4IBc1EowGSoFazakbOAAB9hHEJLQ9BSoIQFNLJFQ2QoZE2vcow2SVYUmiGlPDlEA)

The problem is, TypeScript seems to be deriving the type of value (`value: T[K]`) as 'the types of all accessible by *all* keys of T' rather than using just the key provided in the column object.

Why is TypeScript doing this, and how can I solve it?

What would make some good answer is defining some specific terms and concepts.

I imagine I want to change my `K extends keyof T` to be something like 'K is a keyof T, but only  one key, and it never changes'.

Comment: Can't check it right now, but will `key: "bar" as const` instead of just `key: "bar"` help?

Comment: @Cerberus nope - I tried that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you expect the keys of `T` to be a [*union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of [literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) like `"bong" | "bing" | ...` (and not just `string`), then you can express a type which is itself the *union* of `Column<T, K>` for each key `K` in `keyof T`.

I usually do this via immediately [indexing (lookup)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type SomeColumn<T extends RowData> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Column<T, K>
}[keyof T]
```

but you can also do it via [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type SomeColumn<T extends RowData> = keyof T extends infer K ?
  K extends keyof T ? Column<T, K> : never : never;
```

Either way, your `RowsAndColumns` type would then use `SomeColumn` instead of `Column`:

```
type RowsAndColumns<T extends RowData> = {
  rows: Array<T>;
  columns: Array<SomeColumn<T>>;
}
```

And this makes your desired use case work as expected without compile errors:

```
myFn({
  rows: [
    {
      id: "foo",
      bar: "bar",
      bing: "bing",
      bong: {
        a: 99,
        b: "aaa"
      }
    }
  ],
  columns: [
    {
      key: "bar",
      action: (value, rowData) => {
        console.log(value);
      }
    },
    {
      key: "bong",
      action: (value, rowData) => {
        console.log(value.a);
      }
    },
  ]
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwCIENgqgXlhAxnAJwBMAeAZ2AIEsA7AcwBooBXGgaxsRoD4oAyKAG8oVIgC4oFavSgBfANwAoZaEhQAwnAA2zALY0SAFSgQAHsAg0iZWIlTomAaRPnL1qGwgg4AMyiHebEFFKA8vCUclUJRcYCo4GgkACgA3FB0ICUMAbUcAXSYCOzQULIBKLF4UuFElWRVwaABlOF0ITR19IxcLKxt4ZBLAoRCoXJEaMO8-QzyAWgB+CQ69A0MnbkVZbM9p-zzlAHoAKihVZtb27VXus173AfsUYd3ffx63G1ofCAIoZwWo2cd0+UzexgWGmuXXW-14EhoEBSvygCKRv3kUGOh2UinOtgQZAAglYVvoyLdXH0CU9hsFQkVCRIiQQCCgQEZuFEoPhOjQyMzWeySC02mS1twuVtcT5WLF4pNdCAAGJrD7Ux5DJL4Gg+Kh0CQDYmk6H8zkVYLS5RK1VJelQRkCsajUL20KhUQSABEPjgcC9TBd7oARigCN7QwQA0HQsHaAaoF64-Ro+6QwkE2601BSlAAJx5hgxkPelBlr3F+ppqtQAqjXmrJ3ZINZ0K7CNh1PZmJxBLJNIZQrFdAVTC8VvunVkbQQAB0WjgdFS6WYEDK3OrQdkRbTE-bieDGa7aZ7Cv7K4gQ8GI8qI2zk4S060c4XS4Hq9nKHXla3O9rW2-XFlCAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! What is that `-?` syntax - I have never seen that.

Comment: It removes the optional modifier from properties on the mapped type (otherwise you get weird `undefined`s in the value types); see [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers)

Comment: Your answers are amazing, thank you so much! :3

Comment: commenting to say this does not work as of TS 4.8.4

Comment: @AbeCaymo I just looked and I don't see any obvious problem; could you elaborate on what, specifically, "does not work"?