# Typescript: typesafety for object must have all keys in array values

Tags: typescript

In Typescript ^3.8, given this interface...

```js
interface IEndpoint { method: 'get'|'put'|'post'|'patch'|'delete', path: string }
```

and this constant...

```js
const endpoint = { method: 'get', path: '/first/:firstId/second/:secondId' }
```

Note that `:firstId` and `:secondId` are path parameters that will be dynamically provided at runtime.  I have a function that will take the endpoint and an object with param values, and return the url.

```js
function buildEndpointUrl(endpoint: IEndpoint, map: {[key: string]: string}): string;
```

So, for instance:

```js
// will set url to '/first/123/second/456'
const url = buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, {firstId: '123', secondId: '456'});
```

The challenge I'm facing is that the compiler will allow garbage to be passed as the 2nd param: how do I define `IEndpoint` and `buildEndpointUrl` so that the compiler throws an error if the object provided as the second parameter is missing a required key?

Here is what I've tried:

```js
interface IEndpoint<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> { 
  method: 'get'|'put'|'post'|'patch'|'delete', 
  path: string
}

const endpoint: IEndpoint<['firstId', 'secondId']> = {...};

function buildEndpointUrl<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(
  endpoint: IEndpointConfig<T>, 
  map: {[key: T[number]]: string} // compiler error
);
```

the last line throws a compiler error:

> TS1023: An index signature parameter must be either "string" or "number"

I expected `T[number]` to be equivalent to `string` since `T extends ReadonlyArray<string>` but apparently not.  How should I setup my definition to add type safety?

Comment: At least `[key: T[number]]: string` should be `[key: number]: string`

Comment: I don't think that would work.  It will not enforce the parameter to have the required properties.  With my example above, if I supply `IEndpoint<['firstId', 'secondId']>` as the first function param, I want Typescript to infer that the second param must be of type `{firstId: string, secondId: string}`

Comment: Should a call look like `buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, ['firstId', 'secondId']);`?

Comment: No;the 2nd param is an object that is used to map the name of the route param ('firstId') to its value ('123').  I gave an example in my post.

Comment: I feel like this question and answer is going to be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744734/typescript-keyof-index-type-is-too-wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a mapped type instead of an index signature. The predefined mapped type `Record` will work

```
export interface IEndpoint<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> { 
  method: 'get'|'put'|'post'|'patch'|'delete', 
  path: string
}

const endpoint: IEndpoint<['firstId', 'secondId']> =  { method: 'get', path: '/first/:firstId/second/:secondId' };

declare function buildEndpointUrl<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(
  endpoint: IEndpoint<T>, 
  map: Record<T[number],string> // compiler error
): void;

const b = buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, { firstId: "", secondId:"", test: "" })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFEkATSZGAHgBU5RVSBnOAJWExIiQBsBPAQShRMvSoxhRkAcwB8MuAG84AKDhwAtsBgALCCQBccAORStRgD5GwAVxgWrEcfbCYY2bfZLBuW4EYA0KmouOobikkhSygC+ysrYXOJ0pOQohkQpEBSUANpG6AhQ4vgkAcaMwAmkJUYAuvIAvGpKmjp6hiZmgSHaHQD0BUUwffqDxSR9FVUT+lNcJDVw0QDccV7Y3JhQeOjWSNgwCFxwAEbWCNwkxGRZKACqUNw0dCAMJMxsHFx8gsKi4dI5AAKVTJG4UdLXVJUagyQKg9SYMCGNgJKAkGg5JDWdQnNC1fwAyLyPp9OAJdRgC5oOhCaDKACUhgAblkSKt4ol4Cc4E0zhcrpkKA9uEDgEKUIElGMYCVDAAieWBObVAyKwKocQK+VLBlAA)

Note in 4.1 you can also use [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) to actually extract the parameters from the path string

```
export interface IEndpoint<T extends string> { 
  method: 'get'|'put'|'post'|'patch'|'delete', 
  path: T
}

type ExtractParameters<T extends string> = 
  T extends `${infer Prefix}/:${infer Param}/${infer Suffix}` ? Record<Param, string> & ExtractParameters<Suffix> & [Prefix, Suffix, Param] :
  T extends `${infer Prefix}/:${infer Param}` ? Record<Param, string>  :
  T extends `:${infer Param}`? Record<Param, string> :
  { T: T}

type X = "second/:secondId" extends `${infer Prefix}/:${infer Param}/${infer Suffix}` ? [Prefix, Param, Suffix] : "";
type Y = ExtractParameters<"/first/:firstId/second/:secondId">

const endpoint =  { method: 'get', path: '/first/:firstId/second/:secondId' } as const

declare function buildEndpointUrl<T extends string>(
  endpoint: IEndpoint<T>, 
  map: ExtractParameters<T>
): void;

const b = buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, { firstId: "", secondId:"", test: "" })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFEkATSZGAHgBU5RVSBnORmKZAcwD44BvOAFBw4AW2AwAFhBIAuOAHIO4+QB95YAK4xV6iKx1hMMbBJ0lgAG3HB5AGkHDDkudQEBfAQJgBPMHkIgbDgwAAqYUJhiqFCMNHSBwEwsbJw8ALwOcLT0iSTMAAYAJLzI6GhwIVDA6AggbgD0MsWl5WERIg3NSGVQcADKGug1dflwAPxwAErA2NAklG2R9qzsSNxwAGRwAUHYoeGR1jGUA0O1PFsA2pXVtfanw-aLIgC6cDJCWfEMeXBFJd1WlVhg0mgCehUDh1RhNprMoPNnssUmseO9PtkEkl8mCWr1nm58rCZnMFlDkat1h9hPxqC4PF5fHgABpwDIAIkYJNIjS5s1I+BI7O+uQKXQhNxBjXFrShnXB5QetUJ4zg12Bd0h7Xug2Gbzk7PZAG5GX44ABNNnbQIRPbPI6xdn1GoxGCNF2sQX1PkQHkyH0CoVcTz81h0UjkFBWviicRSWQKJTaexOCRyeTOhCu91Zz0kb3c-P+wuC+RwNxwTDMUMwTzmbAWcJ4dAaJB7BC+uAAIw0CAsJGIZAgFAAqlALHEckkVqkABSfXKRmByIgR4coGhceyfESYMByHa2-btB2bgQASjkADdhyQTQIa92rT2+wO16Px7PF+uYPZ+B6YEFA12WWEtZENexUFYYDy3PAQgA)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost got it:

```
type EndpointParams = ReadonlyArray<string>;

interface IEndpoint<T extends EndpointParams> { 
  method: 'get'|'put'|'post'|'patch'|'delete', 
  path: string
}

function buildEndpointUrl<T extends EndpointParams>(
  endpoint: IEndpoint<T>, 
  map: {[key in T[number]]: string} // In your case it should be mapped, not just indexed
) {}

const endpoint: IEndpoint<['first', 'second']> = {
    method: "get",
    path: "",
};

buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, { // failed
    first: "v1",
    p2: "v2",
});

buildEndpointUrl(endpoint, { // passed
    first: "v1",
    second: "v2",
});
```