# Narrowing type of T[K] when using K extends keyof T

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to define an interface where:

- one property is the key of a generic type
- another property relies on the type of the *value* associated with that key from the other property

The closest I can get is for Typescript to resolve T[K] to the union types of all values of T.  But it seems like there should be some way to narrow that further if K is a known string literal.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

Test

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

interface ColumnDef<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K;
    renderData: (value: T[K]) => void;
}

interface Report<T> {
    columns: ColumnDef<T, keyof T>[];
}

const report: Report<Person> = {
    columns: [
        {
            key: "age", // this is correctly typed to be "age"|"name"
            renderData: (value) => {
                // ideally value should be "number" here, but it is "string|number"
            }
        },
        {
            key: "name", // this is correctly typed to be "age"|"name"
            renderData: (value) => {
                // ideally value should be "string" here, but it is "string|number"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I strongly believe that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744734/typescript-keyof-index-type-is-too-wide answer will help you. I would even say, that your question is dublicate

Comment: This does appear to be related.  I'll look over that question and see if I can apply it to my situation.

Comment: You're right, that was exactly what I needed.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Following the related question linked from captain-yossarian, I was able to narrow the type using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64753409/10868409).

In case it helps someone further, here is how I applied that to my example case.

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

type ColumnDef<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: BaseColumnDef<T, K>
  }[keyof T]


interface BaseColumnDef<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K;
    renderData: (value: T[K]) => void;
}

interface Report<T> {
    columns: ColumnDef<T>[];
}

const report: Report<Person> = {
    columns: [
        {
            key: "age", // this is correctly typed to be "age"|"name"
            renderData: (value) => {
                // value is now type "number"
            }
        },
        {
            key: "name", // this is correctly typed to be "age"|"name"
            renderData: (value) => {
                // value is now type "string"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```