# Why does indexing into a mapped type keep the type narrow?

Tags: typescript

This question is a follow up to this fantastic answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64753409/1068446

What I'm wondering is *why* does the indexing in the mapped type trick work?

To give an example:

```js
type MyData = {
  a: {
    alpha: string; 
  }; 
  b: {
    beta: number; 
  }
}

type NotNarrowPayload<T extends MyData> = {
  key: keyof T; 
  fn: (data: T[keyof T]) => void; 
}

type NarrowDataPayload<T extends MyData> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    key: K; 
    fn: (data: T[K]) => void; 
  }
}[keyof T]; 


function acceptsMTVTFunction<T extends MyData>(baseData: T,fn: NotNarrowPayload<T>) {

}


function acceptsMTVTFunction2<T extends MyData>(baseData: T,fn: NarrowDataPayload<T>) {

}



acceptsMTVTFunction(
    {
    a: {
      alpha: "a"
    }, 
    b: {
      beta: 99
    },
  }, 
  {
    key: "a", 
    fn: (data) => {
      // TypeScript doesn't match the key to the value type, and this makes sense. 
      // (parameter) data: {
      //     alpha: string;
      // } | {
      //     beta: number;
      // }
  }
}
); 



acceptsMTVTFunction2(
  {
    a: {
      alpha: "a"
    }, 
    b: {
      beta: 99
    },
  }, 
  {
    key: "a", 
    fn: (data) => {
      //       (parameter) data: {
      //     alpha: string;
      // }
  }
}
);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYioF4oG8BQUqIC4tc98AbMAC0KgGdgAnASwDsBzAbihIF8uSARkRykoAiCiIsArgFtxDfnh7YV2UJCgA5APbAtiBgx0B3AAqIQZHYgAmAHgAqUCAA9gEFrdqwEyRAB86MR4ANYQIEThIDoAZlCOSlCxLEQAFLb+RI4A2tFxCQC6AJToQQBuOky2-Goa0AZGpkgoFlY2Ds5uHl4+cC2BwSJQOQDSUKxQ+fGOhcIkYRFEo0l4KemZkgljJWVQldVJKjx5EQWz-NjYsdIsAMbATDos+Hd3EGDAtDCOAGqOADFbg8niwnC53J5vL4BgE0gJELQIANsgAadbaPSNYzmSzWOxOAKlHCqK7XYGPZ6vd6fb5-QEU0EAJnB3ShfT8KDhCKRKIS6NS2kMOIGbXxnSJxFJZMQbw+Xx+-yB90pLDSCxCpBow1EiAo1CIACJEIaNTxUdxREJNVaJDQAJz2s2o3gWkg6qZLKDGw1u0QYjL+UpoIIevAAenDUDSYEMiFkEggDFKm21GojUd1+po9GY7A46agkagPCgAB8baRi7atjJ5EmC6IMyXeKTipcrrKaQr6cqQc8meq8B6003yFQaD7nZbSNaw2I7URHc7XTOPdEjSa-aQA6ng6HC9WmzG4wmPMmoKn5mOj3g9ROiLnWJxD1GVMo2wWyUA)

Now, to be clear - I understand by the first approach *doesn't* work.

But what I'm not understanding is why the second approach *does* work.

If we take a closer look at this:

```
type NarrowDataPayload<T extends MyData> = { // We're declaring an object 
  [K in keyof T]: { // For each key in T, it will have a property
    key: K; // And these values will depend on T and K 
    fn: (data: T[K]) => void; 
  }
}[keyof T]; // But only keep the types accessible by keyof T.
```

So the thing is - how does TypeScript know in this case that the key type we have used here is "a" and not "b".

Comment: (Ok, I got the answer as I was writing this - I will post soon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript *doesn't* know how to distinguish the key type, look at how the `NarrowDataPayload` resolves:

```js
const data = {
  a: {
    alpha: "a"
  },
  b: {
    beta: 99
  }
}; 


type A = NarrowDataPayload<typeof data>; 

// type A = {
//     key: "a";
//     fn: (data: {
//         alpha: string;
//     }) => void;
// } | {
//     key: "b";
//     fn: (data: {
//         beta: number;
//     }) => void;
// }
```

It's a union type.

What the index into the type mapping trick does is it keeps the `key` and `fn` aligned - and that's the improvement you're getting from the earlier approach.